# Sails.js model method (non-instance)

Tags: methods, model, sails.js

I've been working on this app for a while.  I have several other modules that all work fine.  I've been having a ton of trouble with this particular module and it's super frustrating.  This problem looks super simple.  Maybe I'm over thinking it.  Hopefully someone will say that I am.  :)

In this module, I decided to use methods from my model.  This particular one is non-instanced.  Here is my model:

```
/*
 * Account.js
 */

module.exports = {

  connection: 'islMongo',

  attributes: {
    name: {
      type: 'string',
      required: true,
    },
  },

  numberToName: function(accountNumber) {
    Account.findOne(accountNumber).exec(function(err, a){
      if (err) {
        return 'err';
      } else {
        return 'ok';
      }
    });
    return 'broke';
  },
};
```

I call it from one of my controllers like this:

```
var accountName = Account.numberToName(params.id);
```

At this point **accountName**'s value is "broke".  I don't understand why it wouldn't either return "err" or "ok".  I simplified my actual function here for testing.

**Edit**:

I have other calls that work properly.  For instance:

```
  updateBalance: function(account, amount, callback) {
    /* Accepts account id or account object */
    (function _lookupAccount(afterLookup) {
      if (typeof account === 'object') return afterLookup(null, account);
      Account.findOne(account)
      .exec(afterLookup);
    })(function (err, a) {
      if (err) return callback(err);
      if (!a) {
        err = new Error();
        err.message = "Couldn't find account.";
        err.status = 400;
        return callback(err);
      }
      a.balance = parseInt(a.balance) + parseInt(amount);
      a.save(callback);
    });
  },
```

Is called like this:

```
Account.updateBalance(params.account, -2000);
```

The definition has a callback, but I don't actually use one because it isn't needed.  The method works fine.

Sails.js [documentation](http://sailsjs.org/documentation/concepts/models-and-orm/models) provides example methods that don't use callbacks.  They simply return the requested data.

```
// Attribute methods
getFullName: function (){
  return this.firstName + ' ' + this.lastName;
},
isMarried: function () {
  return !!this.spouse;
},
isEligibleForSocialSecurity: function (){
  return this.age >= 65;
},
encryptPassword: function () {

}
```

And called like this:

```
if ( rick.isMarried() ) {
  // ...
}
```

Which is what I am trying to do with my method at the top of this post.  It seems like the **exec()** portion of **Account.findOne()** isn't even being called.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sails.js & Node.js are asynchronous. So in simple words they don't wait for response from database, but when they got date they call a callback. So you need to read about [Queries and callbacks](http://sailsjs.org/documentation/reference/waterline-orm/queries) and what is [callback hell](http://callbackhell.com/) (you should never do that).

And now get back to your problem.

```js
/*
Account.js
*/
//...

numberToName: function(accountNumber, callback) {
    // if you want some additional logic you can create function here and call callback in it
    Account.findOne(accountNumber).exec(callback);
}

//...
```

Tip: callbacks first param is always error.

```js
// AccountController

method: function(req, res){
    var id = req.param('id'); // if its int you should parseInt()
    var callback = function(error, account){
        if(error)
            res.send('error');
        else
            res.send(account.name);
    };

    Account.numberToName(id, callback);   
}
```

Comment: thanks for your reply.  Please read over my original post.  I have made some edits.

Comment: Methods can use return if they are not async. All DB methods are so you need to use callback  like in updateBalance. It is the core difference between node and other programming languages. Add some debug in your code like sails.log(err,a) and you will see if it is executed. Method write like this will always return 'broke'

Comment: Interesting.  Thank you for your additional help.  I'm reading over your callback hell link thoroughly now.  :)

Comment: I got it all fixed up.  Definitely a helpful link.  It's a huge difference from the other languages I'm used to.  Because of the similarity in syntax, I didn't think the difference would be so great.  Thanks again!